# SQL server HA when running with PCI Flash device

Tags: sql, vmware-esx, ssd, mirror, flash

I want to purchase a [PCI based Flash storage device](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/solid-state-drives/solid-state-drives-910-series.html) for our ESXi server hosting our SQL Server  machine.

1. We use SQL Server 2008 standard edition.
2. storage is on Netapp via NFS.
3. It is a VM (ESXi 5.1)

Since I don't think I can trust the single PCI device as I do with Netapp I want to be able to fall back as quickly as possible.

What are my best (quick and cheap) options for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a single ESXi host? Are you in a cluster? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: single ESXi host. no cluster.